# From $32\cdot (\frac{1-.5^n}{1-.5})$ to $\frac{64(2^n-1)}{2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I have to prove that  $32\cdot (\frac{1-.5^n}{1-.5})$ is equal to $\frac{64(2^n-1)}{2^n}$

I know that they are equal because when I put them in my calculator the graphs are the same. However, I'd like to do this manually.

So far I have done:
$$32\cdot (\frac{1-.5^n}{1-.5}) = 32 \cdot (\frac{.5}{.5} + \frac{.5^n}{.5}) = 32 \cdot (\frac{.5\cdot.5^n}{.5}) = \frac{32\cdot.5\cdot.5^n}{.5}= \frac{8^n}{.5} $$

How do I solve this?

Comment: Hint: Multiply left hand side top and bottom by $2^n$ as a first step, simplify $1-0.5$ as $0.5$.

Comment: @imranfat Why $2^n$?

Comment: Because it works!, just try :)

Comment: @imranfat Yes I believe you, what I want to know is why it works

Comment: Just to be clear, I meant to multiply left hand side top and bottom by $2^n$ in your original post. (Title!). The expression $8^n/.5$ is incorrect...The reason why it works,well....it's algebra. Don't know what else to say. The important thing that is needed is that $(2^n)(0.5)^n=1$

Comment: "Why it works" isn't really the right question to ask.  Actually, that's technically (part of) the question you're supposed to answer.  You're asked to prove an equality.  The equality can be proven by starting as imranfat suggested.  Then you show why that works by continuing the algebra to get the desired result.  Such is the joy of math proofs.. you don't have to explain how you came up with a working method.  You only have to show that it works.

Comment: It would be clearer to write $.5$ as $0.5$, and also to use $(...)(...)$ to indicate multiplication when dealing with decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't be afraid of writing $.5 = \frac 12$

$32* (\frac{1-.5^n}{1-.5})=$

$2^5(\frac{1 - \frac 12^n}{\frac 12})=$

$2^6(1 - \frac 12^n)=$

$2^6(1 - \frac 12^n)\frac{2^n}{2^n}=$

$2^6\frac{2^n - 1}{2^n}=$

$64\frac{2^n - 1}{2^n}=$

Answer (score 1):

Easier to start from the right.

$$\begin{align}\frac {64(2^n-1)}{2^n}
&=64\left(\frac {2^n}{2^n}-\frac 1{2^n}\right)\\\\
&=\frac {32}{0.5}\left(1-\left(\frac 12\right)^n\right)\\\\
&=\frac{32(1-0.5^n)}{1-0.5}
\end{align}$$